# Image resize without Imagick and losing transparency

Tags: php, resize, imagick

Is there a way, to resize images with formats: `GIF`, `PNG`, `JP(E)G`, without installing additional classes like Imagick?

The most important thing is that images can't lose their transparency (PNG, GIF) and also in case if it's animated, resize it, but without losing `GIF` animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php has an extension called `GD` that should be installed

[GD Extension Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

that you can use.  On the page above are a bunch of examples to do exactly what you want to do.  I personally haven't used it for animated GIF images, but have for the other image formats.  One thing though is that JPEG images use **A LOT** of RAM with this library because the library decompresses the JPEG image into its byte format - essentially making it the equivalent of a 16.7 Million color Bitmap.

To see if the extension is loaded you can call the `extension_loaded('GD')` function and it will return `TRUE` if it is.  Or you can type at the command-line `php -m` and see all the extensions there.  `php -m | grep -i gd` should do it.

Just to be clear, the `GD` library is not very efficent so reconsider using the Imagick extension.

EDIT:
[Resize image sample using GD Extension](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/05/07/resizing-images-in-php-with-gd-and-imagick/)

Comment: Thank you, could you please give me some examples on how should I resize the images using `GD`? I'm in progress of writing my own web application, and I dont to force the users to use Imagick (even if its much better than GD).

Comment: Try this:  http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/05/07/resizing-images-in-php-with-gd-and-imagick/